# При передачи ссылки показывается старый логотип

Tags: оптимизация-сайтов

Когда кому скидываю ссылку на свой сайт - в ссылке не тот логотип, что сейчас, а старый. Уже все перерыл - не могу понять, почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, старая версия логотипа закешировалась у тех, кому вы отправляете ссылку. Для того, чтобы принудить браузеры забрать актуальную версию изображения, в ссылке на иллюстрацию укажите любой GET-параметр.

Например *(где «v2» — get-параметр):*

```
<img src="/images/logo.png?v2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Кэширование нужно либо запретить, либо правильно настроить, что бы не возникало подобных ситуаций.

Можно еще так сделать

```
<img src="/images/logo.png?<? echo rand(); ?>" />
```

Но это все костыли

Comment: Это версия для PHP. Т.к. у Diefair не указана платформа — может не сработать.